# App Store link "rate the application" in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, hyperlink, app-store

I just updated my "Rate the application" button that I'm using in all my apps. Actually, I would prefer to get not only a rating but a rating + a comment.

So I replaced this:

```
if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
}
```

By this:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/app/(AppName)/(AppID)?action=write-review")!
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

And it's working perfectly fine!

But now, I'm wondering what should I do about the "encryption request" from Apple? Some people say there's no need for a "https" call to the App Store but Apple says a bit different: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev88f5c7bf9

What you guys are doing? Did you asked a document from the BIS or not?